# Multiple URL for one post

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, mapping

I am currently struggling with Wordpress and rewrites. I hope you can help me a little.

Following situation:

- I build a small plugin that does the following:

  - register a new post type (called "shop")
  - create a post of this post type (post is called "shopinstance")
  - add content to this post

    - content is some javascript where  the JS mounts a shop (the shop supports pushstate URL) into this post

What does work:

- I can access the post via the URL {domain}/shop/shopinstance. This works perfectly fine

What does not work:

- I can NOT access the post via the URL {domain}/shop/shopinstance/product.

What my intention is:

- The URL {domain}/shop/shopinstance/product-123 or {domain}/shop/shopinstance/product-abc should load the content that is placed in  {domain}/shop/shopinstance/ so that the shop that is on this page can use the /product to identify what content to load
- Therefore the URL should be kept but it should be "mapped" to the post

Side conditions:

- It should be fixed from within the plugin
- I do not want to change functions.php/htaccess or something else

I played around with add_rewrite_rule but I can't get it to work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress won't behave like that by default. If `product` is a separate custom post type, you'd get to it via `{domain}/product/specific_product/`. It's possible to link `products` to `shops` (or any custom post type to any other) but you'd then represent that link as metadata and access it that way.